# How can I download the contents of an eduPad page using wget?

Tags: html, wget

I am using an online eduPad for collaboratively editing some texts. eduPad is a system that lets quickly create a text-only document that can be edited. It is based on Etherpad, but using the Etherpad Api fails because I could not figure out the Api key. Each document has a specific URL under which the textfile is shown. I would like to automatically download the eduPad page's content using a command line tool like wget. However, when I load the page with

```
wget <address of eduPad page>
```

I only get the HTML page with the scripts to display the data, but not my text. Is it possible to download (and refresh) the contents of an eduPad page using wget or a similar tool?

As an example, the page `https://edupad.ch/p/xomgoEj4NY` currently contains the text above.

Comment: what's the site, and what's the content you want to have? be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is generated by [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), you need a `JS` aware tool, like `puppeteer` [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) library:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://example.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    
    const html = await page.evaluate(() => document.documentElement.outerHTML);
    console.log(html);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

##### Usage

```
npm i puppeteer # install puppeteer library as a dependency for nodejs

nodejs wget.js
```

Comment: I tried your approach with the address above but instead of the page's content, I get a large response with mostly code describing the interface, without including any text from the page.

Comment: It's the HTMl of the full page. Try `links -dump file or https://example.com`